# Simple regular expression, why this not works?

Tags: python, regex

```
re.compile("a[b|c]d").findall("akjh adc abc abbd acd")
```

why this returns only

```
['acd']
```

not

```
['abd', 'acd']
```

?

**EDIT:**

I gave wrong example... thats why.  Post can be deleted..

Comment: sorry, stupid mistake... eh...

Comment: the string doesnt contain 'abd'

Comment: no need to edit, just delete it. Also check out the answers about the `|` pipe issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches any string starting with `a`, ending with `d` and with either a `b`, a `|` or a `c`.

If you are looking for have either a `b` or a `c` between `a` and `d`, you use the square brackets without the pipe (`a[bc]d`) *or* you use parenthesis with the pipe (`a(b|c)d`). The square brackets means that *any* character between them is accepted one time (including the `|`); the parenthesis means that any of the regexes separated by `|` are accepted - and in this case you would have two regexes, one matching `b` only and one matching `c` only.

I find the first option the best one. However, these regexes would not match `abc` in any way. There are a lot of regexes which can match both strings, such as `a[bc][cd]` or (which makes more sense to me) `a(bc|cd)`.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression will match a string starting with a, followed by b or c and then d. That is:

'abd'

or

'acd'

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the pipe in the character class

```
re.compile("a[bc]d").findall("akjh adc abc abbd acd")
```

the pattern says, search for `a`, then `b` or `c` (ie, anything in the character class) and then `d`. So the regex only returns 1 finding.